# PyFlink KafkaSink throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I am trying to read a kafka topic and write the same in another kafka topic using KafkaSource/KafkaSink in pyflink (flink version 1.16). Reading from kafka topic works and I am able to print the result but when trying to send to kafka using KafkaSink I get the following exception:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/reddit-anomaly-detection-job/main.py", line 75, in <module>
        main()
      File "/home/.../PycharmProjects/reddit-anomaly-detection-job/main.py", line 49, in main
        kafka_producer = KafkaSink.builder() \
      File "/home/.../.conda/envs/reddit-anomaly-detection-job/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyflink/datastream/connectors/kafka.py", line 963, in set_record_serializer
        get_field_value(j_topic_selector, 'topicSelector').getClass().getCanonicalName()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

The code is:

```
# Create a Kafka producer using the SimpleStringSchema for serialization
record_serializer = KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder() \
    .set_topic(kafka_sink_topic) \
    .set_value_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema()) \
    .build()

kafka_producer = KafkaSink.builder() \
    .set_bootstrap_servers(bootstrap_servers) \
    .set_record_serializer(record_serializer) \
    .build()
```

UPDATE: It seems like the problem is from the local env. The same code runs in ververica on top of a custom python image. I tried to follow [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/pyflink-getting-started) article but with kafka and it is not working locally in PyCharm

Comment: Is this the full error trace?

Comment: @Priyank Yes, only that

Comment: Could be that your topic names are `None`?

Comment: @Priyank I am sure this is not the case, as when I try to use the old way:

    kafka_producer = FlinkKafkaProducer(
        kafka_sink_topic,
        SimpleStringSchema(),
        sink_properties,
        semantic=Semantic.AT_LEAST_ONCE
    ) 
...
 input_stream.add_sink(kafka_producer)
with the same topic name, everything works fine